# How can I get the same coordinates on an html page when it is full screen and when it is not full screen?

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I have an html page where I am putting images on specific x and y coordinates relative to the window they are in, but when I click my full screen button to make the page go full screen, the images are then slightly off from the coordinates I want them to be. Is there a way I can get the same coordinates when toggling full screen?

```
                    function toggleFullScreen() {
                    var doc = window.document;
                    var docEl = doc.documentElement;
                    var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen || docEl.mozRequestFullScreen || docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen || docEl.msRequestFullscreen;
                    var cancelFullScreen = doc.exitFullscreen || doc.mozCancelFullScreen || doc.webkitExitFullscreen || doc.msExitFullscreen;

                    if (!doc.fullscreenElement && !doc.mozFullScreenElement && !doc.webkitFullscreenElement && !doc.msFullscreenElement) {
                        requestFullScreen.call(docEl);
                        var load = document.getElementById('<%=alreadyLoaded.ClientID%>');
                        load.value = 2;
                    }
                    else {
                        cancelFullScreen.call(doc);
                        var load = document.getElementById('<%=alreadyLoaded.ClientID%>');
                        load.value = 2;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

with this way you will be able to call  toggleFullScreen(); everytime the screen change size , i didnt test the code yet , you can test it and give me some feedback

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
      toggleFullScreen();
     });
```

Comment: Ok, I added the function that toggles the full screen mode.